# Выбрать запись по родителю

Tags: mysql

Суть вопроса:

Есть таблица:

```
id name parent
```

Известно значение parent, но не нужной нам записи, а родительской для выбираемой. При этом уровень "вложения" может меняться от 1 до 3.

Примерно так:

- id name parent

  - 1 name null
  - 2 name 1
  - 3 name1 2
  - 4 name1 3
  - 5 name1 1
  - 6 name1 5

В этом примере надо выбрать те записи, у которых name1, нет потомков и известно, что id родителя равно, например, 1.
Тут будет 4.

Comment: Та структура только для примера, а вообще запрос нужен к бд modx. Сейчас пытаюсь решить рекурсивной функцией на php. Всё работает, но интересно, можно ли сделать такое с помощью запроса. Пока что нагуглил, что mysql рекурсивные запросы не поддерживает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, учитывая ограничение 1-3 уровня вложенности, можно и больше, но глубина должна быть фиксированной, не бесконечная:

```
select nodes.id, nodes.name, nodes.lvl
from
  (select t1.id, t1.name, 1 as lvl from tree t0
     join tree t1 on t0.id = t1.parent
     where t0.id = 1
   union all
   select t2.id, t2.name, 2 from tree t0
     join tree t1 on t0.id = t1.parent
     join tree t2 on t1.id = t2.parent
     where t0.id = 1
   union all
   select t3.id, t3.name, 3 from tree t0
     join tree t1 on t0.id = t1.parent
     join tree t2 on t1.id = t2.parent
     join tree t3 on t2.id = t3.parent
     where t0.id = 1) nodes
left join tree tl on nodes.id = tl.parent
where tl.id is null
and nodes.name = 'name1'
```

В вашем варианте в результате будут узлы 4 и 6.

Для сложных выборок по древовидным структурам (в т.ч. бесконечной вложенности) можно и часто лучше использовать альтернативные структуры хранения деревьев. Например, хранение parents (в виде строки ",11,4,") с фильтрацией через `like "%,$id,%"`, или использование Nested sets, для которых нужны триггеры на вставку/редактирование(для случая переноса поддеревьев между узлами)/удаление.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Про структуру хранения понимаю, но к сожалению в Modx структура от меня не зависит. А про ограничение не знал, попробую использовать.